# How to add external collection to existing database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, bson

I want to add a existing **.bson** file to a database that i have created in MongoDB. I tried using 
`db.collection.copyto()` and `db.cloneCollection()` but no luck.

if anybody could help with any particular method or other way to do the same.
PS : I am new to MongoDB.

Comment: .bson files can be imported using mongorestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mongorestore`

```
mongorestore --database dbName --collection collectionName /path/file.bson
```